# AMP Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, amp-html, ruby-on-rails-5.1, rack-cors

I have problem After google cache my AMP page. I am implementing amp page with rails 5. Using rake-cors gem for cross-origin. Normally page working fine but after the cache is shown console error.

**Error**:

**The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'https://www-myurl-in.cdn.ampproject.org' is therefore not allowed access.**

```
config/application.rb

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins 'https://www-myurl-in.cdn.ampproject.org'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

I don't know where I change in my code, Please help me.

Comment: Can you try making `origins: '*'`.

Comment: yes, but google amp show error to include URL

Comment: Can you try this ? `config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'https://www-myurl-in.cdn.ampproject.org'
    resource '*', 
          :headers => :any, 
          :methods => [:get, :post, :options],
          :credentials => true
  end
end`

Comment: no, but whats difference with my code.

Comment: I have added `credentials` option to the existing code.

Comment: I just put that code into my server and let's see ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After modifying Response Header its working fine.

```
response.headers['AMP-Redirect-To'] = request.protocol+request.host_with_port+url
response.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin'
response.headers['AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin'] = params[:__amp_source_origin]
```